# Nginx - set global auth_basic

Tags: authentication, nginx

I would like to set the auth_basic globally for all the projects with nginx.

It works well by setting in on every project conf with:

```
auth_basic "DEV restricted access";
auth_basic_user_file /var/www/passwd;
```

In order to avoid this to be forgot for new projects, I would like to set this globally. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic), auth_basic can be configured globally by placing the commands within the `http` block.

Depending on your particular flavour of OS, start with the master `nginx.conf` configuration file, and find the `http { ... }` section or possibly an auxiliary configuration file which is pulled into it using an `include` statement.

Comment: Work as a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create file:

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/pick-your-name.conf
```

and put there this piece of text:

```
auth_basic "DEV restricted access";
auth_basic_user_file /var/www/passwd;
```

Works the same as placing it straight into nginx.conf but keeps your configuration clean.